# Dependence of relative humidity on temperature and pressure

Tags: thermodynamics, phase-transition, humidity

How is relative humidity determined by temperature and pressure? What is the equation and its derivation? The following is a specific scenario.

Suppose a cubic container encloses a solution consists of two liquids with known molar fractions and occupies a simply connected strict subdomain of the cube. The solution is stationary and uniformly mixed. The remaining space in the cubic container contains only the vapor from the two liquids. The vapor molecules of two liquids have no interaction with each other but completely elastic collision with the container wall. When the vapor and the liquid are in thermal equilibrium, and each is homogeneous, what is the relative humidity of the two vapors? Can we apply Raoult's law here and equating relative humidity with the fugacity coefficient? If not, what will be a good equation of state for relative humidity in this case?

---

In light of the comments from Chester Miller and David White, I will present the following scenario for air and water vapor.

Suppose we are given a large enclosed cubic container completely rigid and insulated thermally and radiatively from outside. Fill it first with completely dry, still and homogeneous air. Fill quickly a large portion in volume (so large that the mass of the water that would later evaporate is but a negligible portion of the total mass of the water) of the container volume with water with no macroscopic flow within the water. Now the air is still without any water vapor mixed in and is at a certain temperature and pressure. After the water vapor has evaporated into the air and the mix has reached the thermal equilibrium through adiabatic process and without outside work done to the whole closed system, what is the relative humidity of the water vapor? What is the equation of state that governs the process?

Comment: I think there are mainly approximative formulas only.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll address one of the key questions you are asking and, I believe, you'll be able to figure the answers to other questions yourself:

> After the water vapor has evaporated into the air and the mix has
>   reached the thermal equilibrium through adiabatic process and without
>   outside work done to the whole closed system, what is the relative
>   humidity of the water vapor?

The answer to this question is 100%.

The dynamic equilibrium is achieved when the rate of evaporation is equal to the rate of condensation. Condensation happens when the relative humidity is 100%.

In other words, given enough time, the relative humidity in a closed container with water will become 100%.

[This Hyperphysics article](http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/Kinetic/relhum.html) contains some empiric formulas and graphs that will help you determine the density of the saturated vapor as a function of temperature.

Comment: Suppose in a sealed container there is less water molecules than the 100% relative humidity at the dynamic equilibrium would require. Is there still going to be liquid phase water present, or the water molecules are all in the gas phase even at the dynamic thermal equilibrium?

Answer (score 0):

Relative humidity (percent) is defined by $$RH=\frac{p}{p_s(T)}\times 100$$where p is the partial pressure of water vapor in the air and $p_s(T)$ is the equilibrium saturation vapor pressure of water at the air temperature T.  It is not a derived quantity.  You can easily find all this simply by Googling Relative Humidity.

Comment: I know the definition of relative humidity. I am surprised when reading the wikipedia entry https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relative_humidity that it is determined by temperature and pressure as if the two latter quantities control the relative humidity. How do temperature and pressure determine the fraction of the liquid water molecules amongsts all the other vapors in all the volume above the bulk liquid?

Comment: @Hans -- That's yet another poorly written wikipedia article. Relative humidity does not depend on atmospheric pressure. It depends solely on the partial pressure of water vapor in the air and the saturation pressure of water at that temperature. Saturation pressure is highly temperature dependent, but it does not depend on atmospheric pressure.

Comment: I suspect that the author of the article was a bit "loose" with his wording.  Relative humidity depends on *partial* pressure of water vapor in the air, and temperature (which affects the vapor pressure of water).

Comment: @DavidWhite: You say "It depends solely on the partial pressure of water vapor in the air and the saturation pressure of water at that temperature." That is the definition of relative humidity. My question is given a liquid solution, what determines the relative humidity of the vapor above it. I think I have found an idealized answer. That is the ideal solution and the related Raoult's law https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Raoult%27s_law, which states that the relative humidity is simply the mole fraction of the particular liquid in the liquid phase solution. Do you agree?

Comment: I can't say whether or not I agree without you being much more specific regarding the conditions of the problem you are trying to solve.  Are you dealing with water?  What is dissolved in the water?  What concentration?  Is there any air flow involved?  Is there a covered container for the liquid?
Note that your problem may well involve non-ideal vapor-liquid equilibrium, which requires fugacity coefficients rather than Raoult's law.

Comment: @DavidWhite: Good point. I have edited my question adding a detailed and specific example. What do you think?

Comment: @Hans In my engineering experience that is the equation we would have used.

Comment: Addressing your edited version, I don't think that the term relative humidity is ever used for vapor liquid equilibrium of a binary system like this (at least, I've never seen it used).  In my experience, RH is almost exclusively reserved for water and air; it can also be applied to other systems with a non-condensible gas, however.  For a binary system like this, you can talk about the mole fractions of the two components in the liquid and vapor, but, for a non-ideal liquid solution, their relationship is determined by the activities (or fugacities) of the two components in the liquid.

Comment: @Hans, as Chester Miller has suggested, "relative humidity" is not the correct phrase.  You are dealing with vapor-liquid equilibrium.  If your mixture consists of something like two straight-chain alkanes, you can use Raoult's Law and get a good answer.  However, if the mixture consists of polar molecules, salt, etc., there are BIG non-idealities involved, and the problem gets somewhat more complicated, even for a binary mixture.  Thus, you need to be even MORE specific, as the answer strongly depends on what your mixture is composed of.

Comment: @DavidWhite and Chester Miller: I see. I have added a scenario considering the water-air system in the question and asked for the corresponding equation of state.  Could you both examine that?

Comment: @Hans, after equilibrium is reached, the air in the container will be at 100% relative humidity.  This means that the partial pressure of the water vapor will be equal to the vapor pressure of water at the stated temperature.  I would use the Antoine equation to calculate that vapor pressure (which isn't actually an equation of state).  By the way, you obviously have something in mind regarding your posted question, and I seriously doubt that it involves relative humidity.  What general problem are you looking to solve?

Comment: @DavidWhite: My question is about when relative humidity does not reach 100% in the air. I thought there were two possibilities. 1) When the equilibrium has not been reached, for example, when the vapor molecules are continually removed, say by wind. 2)The equilibrium has reached. There are other substances, say other vapors or just other gas molecules, that occupy the space that would have been occupied by water vapor had the space been occupied by water alone. That was why I asked about binary liquid system and Raoult's law. I hope this explains my motivation for the question.

Comment: @DavidWhite:  I do not know when the gas molecules, say air, which is not a liquid and therefore is not present in the liquid part of the system whether we can still use, say, Raoult's law, to obtain the fractional mole of the water vapor.

Comment: @Hans, it's my experience that the vapor pressure of water is independent of the air in the container.  Unless you require extreme accuracy and precision, you can ignore the air in the container.  If, on the other hand, you are dealing with a high air pressure situation, where there is more than a minuscule amount of air dissolved in the water phase, the answer may be different.  Can you be more specific on what problem you are trying to solve?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/59959/discussion-between-hans-and-david-white).

Comment: @Hans, please go to chat.